# Is there an infinite loop in my code for solving Collatz sequence?

Tags: ruby

My code is trying to find the answer to this problem: The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:

```
n → n/2 (n is even)
n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
```

Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:

```
13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
```

It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.

Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

And here is my code:

```
step_count = 1
score = {}
largest_score = 1
(1..1000000).map do |n|
  while n >= 1 do
    if n%2 == 0 then
      n/2
      step_count += 1
    else
      (3*n)+1
      step_count += 1
    end
  end
  score = {n => step_count}
end
score.each {|n, step_count| largest_score = step_count if largest_score < step_count}
puts score.key(largest_score)
```

I ran it for over an hour and still no answer. Is there an infinite loop in my code, or maybe some different problem, and if so what is it?

I am using Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/index.html) for more information about this problem.  I read elsewhere that it has been shown that the longest sequences among those beginning between 1 and n is no longer than the longest sequence among those beginning between n+1 and 2n, suggesting you only have to look at those starting between 500001 and 1000000.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you've got an infinite loop. It's here:

```
while n >= 1 do
  if n%2 == 0 then
    n/2
    step_count += 1
  else
    (3*n)+1
    step_count += 1
  end
end
```

The condition in your `while` loop is testing `n`, but nothing within the loop is changing its value. What you probably meant to do is this:

```
while n >= 1 do
  if n % 2 == 0
    n = n / 2
    step_count += 1
  else
    n = (3 * n) + 1
    step_count += 1
  end
end
```

A few sidenotes:

- It looks like you mean to be updating the `score` hash with new key-value pairs, but as written, `score = { n => step_count }` will replace it entirely on each iteration. To add new pairs to the existing Hash, use `score[n] = step_count`.
- It's much more efficient to look up a *value* in a Hash by its *key* than the other way around, so you might want to reverse your Hash storage: `score[step_count] = n`, finding the largest score with `score.each { |step_count, n| #...` and reading it out with `score[largest_score]`. This has the added advantage that you won't have to store all million results; it'll only store the last number you reach that results in a chain of a given length. Of course, it also means that you'll only see one number that results in the largest chain, even if there are multiple numbers that have the same, highest chain length! The problem is worded as though the answer is unique, but if it isn't, you won't find out.
- To debug problems like this in the future, it's handy to drop your loop iterations to something tiny (ten, say) and sprinkle some `puts` statements within your loops to watch what's happening and get a feel for the execution flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How long do you think the code will take to finish?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things, like what kind of hardware you're using and how much else you're running on that machine! If it ran more than a minute or so, though, I'd be suspicious. Try putting some `puts` statements inside your loops to make sure you're making progress or to narrow down where you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution for your problem:

```
def solve(n)
  max_collatz = 0; max_steps = 0
  (1..n).each do |k|
    next if k % 2 == 0
    next if k % 3 != 1
    steps = collatz_sequence_count(k)
    if steps > max_steps
      max_steps   = steps
      max_collatz = k
    end
  end
  max_collatz
  # answer: 837799 with 525 steps, in nearly 2.2 seconds on my machine
end

def collatz_sequence_count(k)
  counter = 1
  while true
    return counter if k == 1
    k = k % 2 == 0 ? k/2 : 3 * k + 1
    counter += 1
  end
end

# You can then use the above methods to get your answer, like this:
answer = solve 1000000
puts "answer is: #{answer}"
```

Results (uses a custom home-brewed gem to solve ProjectEuler problems):

```
nikhgupta at MacBookPro in ~/Code/git/ProjectEuler [ master: ✗ ] 48d
± time euler solve 14                                                                                             +next: 2 | total: 22 | ▸▸▸▹▹▹▹▹▹▹
0014 | Longest Collatz sequence | It took me: 2.166033 seconds. | Solution: 837799
euler solve 14  3.30s user 0.13s system 99% cpu 3.454 total
```

Comment: I ran it in TextMate on my macbook air two gigs of ram and after 48.08 secs it gave me a blank screen

Comment: @user3127905: I can not think of a reason. Updated the answer with the result from my run.

Comment: Where does it put the answer, as in, what variable should have the answer after it is done?

Comment: @user3127905: oh! the `solve 1000000` line returns the solution. So, you can use a `puts` to display the answer. I have updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Would you please explain the optimization in the outer loop (the two `next if` statements)?

Comment: The outer loop (function _solve_) can be written as `(1..n).reject { |i| i.even? || i % 3 != 1}.max_by { |i| collatz_sequence_count(i) }`.  Written as one line here, but would be best in multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, only that I wanted to calculate the number of steps at that time, if I remember correctly :)

Comment: @WayneConrad: I think I added them because of some mathematical analysis and further confirmation on several smaller inputs. I will try to remember the analysis and update the answer, then.

Comment: It's probably worth checking those optimisations, because, a quick spot check of `(1..10).map { |k| solve(k) }` yields only *one* correct answer out of the 10, stemming from skipping those numbers.